# Removing all rows in a List (with a Realm datasource)?

Tags: swiftui, realm

I'm having problem with my app crashing when deleting all data of a specific type in Realm. The data is made available to the view through a @Published var in my "RealmManager". It looks something like this:

Item

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

class Item: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable {
  @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var id: UUID
  @Persisted var name: String
}
```

RealmManager

```
import Foundation
import RealmSwift

@MainActor
final class RealmManager: ObservableObject {
  @Published private(set) data: [Item] = []
  let realm: Realm?
 
  init() {
    guard let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "seed", withExtension: "realm") else { fatalError("Could not find seed") }
    realm = try! Realm(configuration: Realm.Configuration(schemaVersion: 4, seedFilePath: url))
    updateItems()
  }  

  func updateItems() {
    guard let realm else { return }
    self.data = []
    
    let allObjects = realm.objects(Item.self)
    allObjects.forEach { item in 
      self.data.append(item)
    }
  }

  func deleteAll() {
    guard let realm else { return }
    self.data = []
    let allObjects = realm.objects(Item.self)
    do {
      try realm.write() {
        print("Deleting \(allObjects.count) objects")
        realm.delete(allObjects)
      }
    } catch {
      print("deleteAll(): \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

Then in my view

```
import SwiftUI

struct NameView: View {
  @StateObject private var realmManager = RealmManager()
  
  var body: some View {
    NavigationStack {
      List {
        ForEach(realmManager.data) { item in
          NavigationLink(destination: EmptyView()) {
            Text(item.name)
          }
        }
      }

      Button("Remove all data") {
        realmManager.deleteAll()
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When pressing the "Remove all data"-button, the app sometimes throws a Realm-exception: "Object has been deleted or invalidated."

The only way around the error is:

1. Comment out the ForEach-loop in the view.
   or
2. Add a delay in my deleteAll()-method in RealmManager, like so:

```
func deleteAll() {
  guard let realm else { return }

  DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.data = []
  }

  DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
    let allObjects = realm.objects(Item.self)
    do {
      try realm.write() {
        print("Deleting \(allObjects.count) objects")
        realm.delete(allObjects)
      }
    } catch {
      print("deleteAll(): \(error)")
    }
  }
}
```

It seems like the view is trying to access the @Published data after the objects has been deleted, causing the error. So either not showing the data in the view, or setting the property to an empty array, then waiting a small amount of time before deleting the objects seems to "solve" the problem, but it's a very ugly hack. Anyone know what's going on and how to solve it in a tidy/safe way?

Comment: A common coding issue when working with Realm is to copy/store objects in Arrays instead of the built in collections (results, list, etc). Realm objects are live updating. Meaning that if Realm objects are stored in an array, and then those objects are deleted from Realm, it does NOT delete the index from the array. It's then a nil object and the array count remains the same. There also appears to be unneeded async code and dispatch queues in the question - and that leads to threading issues and is likely the cause or at least contributing. Try `.asyncWrite` or Actors instead.

Comment: I found out about @ObservedResults which seems to solve my problem, but just for fun I'll try using .asyncWrite() to see if that works too.

Comment: ObservedResults allows 'quick writes' aka an implicit write with $ (binding) operator to occur without having to manually open a write transaction so that may do it. If you want to do BIG writes, asyncWrite is something to look into (and ensure the object is thawed!)